# MsBuild reset Library Path

Tags: delphi, msbuild

I'm trying to build distributed delphi project on a non-host dependant environment. As library path depends on the global GUI options, each host could vary from each other.

I'd like to make sure every single host has the same library path, is there any way to reset/overwrite the library path from command line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do this. Don't rely on the search path. Have all the source you need in the source control repo and check it all out together.

Comment: Hi David, I agree, I don't rely on the search path ;), that's why I want to reset it. Sorry if I wrote an ambiguous sentence.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding then. You mention search path and library path. Which is it?

Comment: Ups, yeah, you're right, I mean the library path.

Comment: Then I guess you need to edit the question. So, looking at library path, isn't setting that up part of the Delphi installation process performed when preparing each build machine?

Comment: Question title is still misleading. Details matter.

Comment: "I'd like to make sure every single host has the same library path... coma" - actually there is a part of the question which is answered by the Zam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi IDE -> Options -> Environment Options -> Environment Variables -> create "User overrides". 
For example variable *COMP1* with value D:\Src\Components\ComponentNo1\
For example variable *COMP2* with value D:\Src\Components\ComponentNo2\

Into Environment Options -> Delphi Options -> Library -> Library path replace full path to component into $(COMP1) for Component #1 and $(COMP2) for Component #2.

As result Library path will be independable on end-developer-PC.

Comment: *is there any way to reset/overwrite the library path from command line?*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -- No. My answer -- is just possible alternative solution for "to build distributed delphi project on a non-host dependant environment."

Comment: As I read the question, the asker wants to know **how** to set the library path rather than **what** to set it to.

Comment: However, judging by the accept, I don't understand anything any more!!

Answer (score 2):

The library path is stored in the registry:

```
Key: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\<ver>\Library\Win32
Name: Search Path
Value Type: REG_SZ
```

Different targets, e.g. Win64, OSX32, Android32 etc. have different key names, as can be observed in the registry.

I would regard the setting of the library path as a task to be performed at the time you install Delphi onto the build machine.

Comment: @Mario Did I misunderstand the question? I thought you wanted to know how to set the library path programmatically.

Comment: actually I need two library paths, a local configuration and a distributed building configuration, that's why I want to reset the library path. The below answer solves my issue so far, as static solution, but I'd like to control it using a script.

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. I thought you asked how to set the path programmatically. Is that not what you asked? Anyway, you accepted an answer that doesn't answer the question you asked as I read it. I suspect you've moved on from the question you are asked and thinking about your next problem. I can't really understand what's going on here any more. Never mind.